# Is there a training ground where I can practice using skills and weapons?

Tags: apex-legends

Or is the only way to "practice" by slogging through match after match?

The tutorial is decent in some aspects to practice with some weapons, but doesn't have attachments to play around with or other classes to play as.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Today playing matches is the only way that you can practice "for real".

Lots of features and upgrades are already being included and more are scheduled to improve gameplay, performance and more as producer Drew McCoy wrote via [EA's blog post](https://www.ea.com/en-gb/games/apex-legends/news/letter-to-community).